# Haskell Lists within lists

Tags: list, haskell

I've a homework question where I have to Define a function which with an input in the form of a list with smaller lists of integers it and sums the numbers in each of the innermost lists and then multiplies the resulting sums with each other.

My code is as follows and obviously doesn't work, any help will be greatly appreciated :)

```
sumI :: [Int] -> Int
sumI [] = 0
sumI (x:xs) = x + sumI xs

mapQ :: [[Int]] -> Int
mapQ [] = []
mapQ xs = [product (sumI x) | x <- xs]
```

Answer (score 5):

As it's a homework question - here are a couple of tips.

1. you can use map to apply a function to each member of a list. As the list is made up of lists, a suitable function may be `sum`
2. You want to turn a list into a single number. I mean , you have a list of sums that you need and you want to multiply them together to get a single number. This is quite common, and is handled by one of the many `fold` functions.

Give these a try.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're nearly there. Replace the last line with

```
mapQ xs = product [ sumI x | x <- xs]
```

Comment: ...and remove `mapQ [] = []` :)

Comment: Wonderful that works cheers riccardo! by removing that line what does it actually do?

Comment: @blaneclorley: `mapQ [] = []` says that given an empty list return an empty list back, which is nonsense since your type signature says you want to return `Int`.

Comment: That line had a type mismatch: your type signature says from `[[Int]]` to `Int`, but you were returning a list there ;)